# Method ElevatedButton not define?

Tags: flutter, dart, methods

Compiler message:
lib/home.dart:4:18: Error: This requires the 'non-nullable' experiment to be enabled.
Try enabling this experiment by adding it to the command line when compiling and running.
SignUpForm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
^
lib/home.dart:49:14: Error: The method '[ElevatedButton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6hYW.png)' isn't defined for the class '_SignUpFormState'.

- '_SignUpFormState' is from 'package:formvalidation/home.dart' ('lib/home.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'ElevatedButton'.

Comment: try restart vs-code

Comment: Please format your code and clearly state your issue. We can't differentiate between the code and the issue as it stands.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think it related to Null Safety you can unsound it .
Take a look here : https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety